# Error during installation of VundleVim on Max OSX 10.10.5

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, vundle

I'm attempting to install [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim), the plug-in manager for Vim, and I am following the directions to the letter, but am either really missing something or there's another method I should be using not supplied on their [Github repository](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim).

Step 1. I execute the following in Terminal: `git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim`

step 2. I cd into the following directory so I can edit my vimrc file:

```
/usr/share/vim
```

According to the 3rd step on Vundle Github, I'm to enter the following:

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" The following are examples of different formats supported.
" Keep Plugin commands between vundle#begin/end.
" plugin on GitHub repo
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
" plugin from http://vim-scripts.org/vim/scripts.html
Plugin 'L9'
" Git plugin not hosted on GitHub
Plugin 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
" git repos on your local machine (i.e. when working on your own plugin)
Plugin 'file:///home/gmarik/path/to/plugin'
" The sparkup vim script is in a subdirectory of this repo called vim.
" Pass the path to set the runtimepath properly.
Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
" Avoid a name conflict with L9
Plugin 'user/L9', {'name': 'newL9'}

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line
```

4. I open a new Terminal shell, type `Vim` to launch Vim so I run the following command: `:PluginInstall`

   Here's where I'm stuck, as I get this error in Vim after entering the `:PluginInstall`

   **`E492: Not an editor command: PluginInstall`**

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you try following the steps on this post? http://fideloper.com/mac-vim-tmux

Comment: @Malvin9000 Yes, no luck following those steps either. Tried multiple times.

Comment: Have a look at [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) which is better compared to Vundle and easier to set up.

Comment: Looks like Vundle isn't loaded. Are you sure it's picking up your vimrc file? If not, try setting a different theme before or after initializing vundle just to be sure.

Comment: @n3wjack Just to confirm: I am supposed to be editing the virmc file located in `/usr/share/vim` correct?

Comment: Normally you would edit the file `~/.vimrc` (create it if it doesn't exist).

Comment: @Zach Ok thanks, so just to be clear, I don't want to touch the vimrc file located at  `/usr/share/vim` ?

Comment: I'm not sure on Mac where the vim folder is located, so that was the point. Edit the theme so you see if it gets loaded. Using vim you can figure out where your `.vimrc` file should be located. The home location is stored in the `$HOME` variable, which you can list using `:echo $HOME`, or using `:version`, which also lists what vimrc files are parsed (can be really handy if you're getting weird results.)

Answer (score 2):

> Put this at the top of your .vimrc to use Vundle.

Whatever you find in `/usr/share/vim` is ***not*** yours. That directory is Vim's system-level runtime directory and you have no business doing *anything* there.

Since you `cd`ed in the wrong directory, anything you do after step 3 is bound to fail.

- Third party scripts and custom scripts are to be installed in `~/.vim/`.
- Custom settings and mappings are to be written in `~/.vimrc`.

---

You'l need to revert `/usr/share/vim` to its pristine state if you want Vim to remain stable.

Comment: If there is no  vimrc at `~/.vimrc` should I just create one?

Comment: Yes, that's what you are supposed to do.

Comment: Ok thank you. Should I create the vimrc file in the `~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim` directory? It's not clear in the instructions on Github where I'm supposed to create my new vimrc file.